# Find in mongodb subdocument

Tags: java, mongodb, nosql

I use SpringData. I have document with subdocument, it looks like :

> {
>      "name" : "MongoDB",
>      "type" : "database",
>      "count" : 1,
>      "info" : {
>                  x : 203,
>                  y : 102
>                }
>   }

How can I find all documents with(for example) x=203
Thanks!

Comment: I want to retrieve all documents where x=203

Comment: I asked what have you tried. Not what do you want.

Comment: Something like this code mongoTemplate.find(new Query(Criteria.where("info").elemMatch(Criteria.where("x").is(203))), InfoDocument.class));

Comment: You can't use `$elemMatch` to match a part of document. You can just match directly with the subelements using `.` operator. Probably you can try: - `mongoTemplate.find(new Query(Criteria.where("info.x").is(203))), InfoDocument.class));`

Comment: I have checked it before, it doesnt work

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no way you can get subdocument directly. What you can do is use below query to match the value inside you subdocument. This would retrieve parent document if you criteria for the subdocument succeeds.As Rohit mentioned you can use below query but this return the type of your parent document

```
mongoTemplate.find(new Query(Criteria.where("info.x").is(203))), ParentDocument.class));
```